# ASUS Transformer TF101 freezes on many ROMs

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, system-freeze

## Problem:

I have this TF101, which freezes in virtually every ROM I've tried. When I'm playing a game, refreshing Twitter timeline by dragging down, or sometimes even simply viewing settings, the screen freezes. The sound and logcat however continue. I can also turn the screen on and off by pressing the power button, but the lockscreen does not show up. When I press the volume buttons, *sometimes* logcat says it's registering the presses, but ignores them: `I/InputDispatcher(141): Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.`

[Here's a Youtube video showing the problem.](http://youtu.be/NlSKa0qVkhQ?t=1m)

## Analysis:

As said, logcat continues while the freeze is happening. Here are two logcats of the freeze and a traces.txt:

**Device info:** Stock ROM
**Android version:** 3.1
**Kernel version:** 2.6.36.3-00011-g3eb19ec android@Mercury #1
**Build number:** HMJ37.WW_epad-8.4.4.11-201107011
**S/N:** B70.........
**Problem:** Freeze as mentioned before.
**[Logcat](http://pastebin.com/5K8i5jBm)**

**Device info:** Stock ROM after 2 ASUS updates
**Android version:** 4.0.3
**Kernel version:** 2.6.39.4 android@Mercury #1
**Build number:** IML74K.WW_epad-9.2.1.24-20120503
**S/N:** B70.........
**Problem:** Freeze as mentioned before, but now the device reboots itself short time later.
**[Logcat](http://pastebin.com/JtbPhFRF)**

**Device info:** Prime! 1.8 ROM flashed using NVFlash
**Android version:** 2.3
**Kernel version:** 2.6.36.4-g565dea1 roach@nimda #20110816
**Build number:** HTJ85B.prime_epad-1.8-20110821
**S/N:** B70.........
**Problem:** Freeze as mentioned before. *This is the ROM in which the freezes less frequently happen, but they still happen.*
**[Traces.txt](http://pastebin.com/A0iJ9Z3b)**

## Solution:

I have no idea. That's why I came here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a ROM that does not have this problem, the [newest AOKP](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1542302) ROM.

Answer (score -1):

The t101 is getting long in the tooth. Not sure what version of android you're on (as you probably know kitkat is supposed to be better for older devices) but I expect that many recent ROMs coupled with recent apps, which are much more resource intensive than the apps of 2010 or 2011, are bogging down the tablet's aging insides. If suggest researching 2014 ROMs others have had success with on the T101 and installing one of those and also being vigilant about killing apps you're not using to free up RAM.

Comment: I think apps going a bit slower because they're resource-intensive on older hardware is somewhat different from the screen freezing completely. Also, killing apps to "free up RAM" is counter-productive and makes your device slower: see our many other questions on that subject.